# Codeigniter session problem

Tags: facebook, session, codeigniter

I am building a facebook app with codeigniter. When a user accepts a request and gets redirected to my app I want to store the request_id in a session. At first it gets stored but when the page is reloaded after the user authenticates the app the requested_id stored earlier doesn't exist anymore.

```
function save_request_id()
{       
    $this->session->set_userdata('request_id', $request_id);       
}

function retrieve_request_id()
{

    $data = $this->session->all_userdata();

    print_r($data);

    exit;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to only retrieve the `request_id`:

```
$this->session->userdata('request_id');
```

Comment: I know how to retrive only the request_id Its just that its not stored in the session anymore.

Comment: Did you check your `config.php` file? After how long is the session set to expire?

Comment: its set to expire after 7200 sec.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like the session is being cleared when the user completes the auth cycle. Are you using the FB PHP SDK? If so, I believe it creates its own session to manage the connected user. Check the library you're using, you may need to adjust it to fit your needs - or devise an alternate solution, like redirecting after auth to a view that can process a `request_id` in the URL.

Answer (score 0):

session library of CodeIgniter has this problem,use native php session + secuirty lib of CodeIgniter to clean XSS .